# presigned url for aws s3 in akka java application

Tags: akka, alpakka

I am using Akka framework and writing a Java application that talks to AWS S3. Is there any example of generating a pre-signed get request for s3 in java using Akka framework? Alpakka S3Client does not have any method in its interface to create a pre-signed request.